# How can I get my two images in Canvas not erasing each other?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, sprite-sheet

I am trying to set up little game in Canvas with Html and JS. I encounter one problem and I don't understant what am I missing.

I draw two sprites sheets in the canvas, but when they arrives near each other, the one on the bottom of my drawloop erase the other one.

I import my srpites, draw and animate them and call everything in a drawloop with a setTimeout to reduce the speed of the animations

```
function drawArthur() {
    updateFrame();
    animations();
    resetAnimations();
    context.drawImage(arthurImage, arthur.srcX, arthur.srcY, arthur.width, arthur.height, arthur.x, arthur.y, arthur.width, arthur.height);
    arthurImage.style.zIndex = '1';
}
```

```
function updateFrame() {
    arthur.currentFrame = ++arthur.currentFrame % arthur.colums;
    arthur.srcX = arthur.currentFrame * arthur.width;
    arthur.srcY = 0;
    context.clearRect(arthur.x, arthur.y, arthur.width, arthur.height);

    // if (myModule.newZombie.isCrashed) {
    //     arthur.die = true;
    //     console.log(arthur.die);
    // }
}
```

```
function animations() {
    arthur.srcX = arthur.currentFrame * arthur.width;
    if (arthur.goRight) {
        arthur.srcY = arthur.goRowRight * arthur.height;
    } else if (arthur.goLeft) {
        arthur.srcY = arthur.goRowLeft * arthur.height;
    } else if (arthur.duckRight) {
        arthur.srcY = arthur.duckRowRight * arthur.height;
    } else if (arthur.atkRight) {
        arthur.srcY = arthur.atkRowRight * arthur.height;
        if (zombie.x < 274 && zombie.x > 262) {
            console.log('killllll');
            zombie.dieRight = true;
        } else if (zombie.x < 262) {
            zombie.dieRight = false;
            zombie.x = -50;
        } else if (arthur.jumpRight) {
            arthur.srcY = arthur.jumpRowRight * arthur.height;
        }
    }
}
```

```
// function that reset all states every time in the draw loop to set the states at the origin state
function resetAnimations() {
    arthur.stand = arthur.right;
    arthur.goLeft = false;
    arthur.goRight = false;
    arthur.duckRight = false;
    arthur.atkRight = false;
    arthur.jumpRight = false;
}
```

```
function drawLoop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        drawArthur();
        drawZombie();
        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            drawLoop();
        });
    }, 150);
    createNewZombie();
    console.log(allZombies);
}
```

I cant manage two get my two characters, to just overlap each other. 
The last one in the drawloop, here the Zombie, will erase Arthur when he passes over him.

Thanks !

Comment: Is your drawZombie() method similar to the drawArthur() ? 
You didn't post it

Comment: Hey, no I didn't want to put too much code here. it is the same yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `drawZombie` methods also calls a similar `updateFrame()` method, 
and that it also has a line like `context.clearRect(arthur.x, arthur.y, arthur.width, arthur.height);`

What's happening is that you

1) clear the area behind Arthur

2) draw Arthur

3) clear the area behind Zombie(s) **even if Arthur is behind the Zombie**

4) draw the Zombie(s)

Because you're clearing the entire canvas in `drawLoop` with `context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);` you don't need to then do (1) & (3).

**Remove the `context.clearRect(...)` from the `updateFrame` methods.**

or

**If you do want to have those extra `clearRect(...)` just make sure that they all happen before you draw Arthur and the Zombie(s)**

Hope this helps